# IIS 6 not serving up asp.net 1.1 pages?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-1.1

Ok, this is strange.  Some background

- Windows 2003 R2 SP2 32-bit
- IIS 6.0

I've got a very simple dot.net 1.1 example app that just echoes something to the screen via a response.write.  Works fine on my workstation. Once I deploy it to this server, when i go to the page, it wouldn't render but instead serves up the source code of my aspx file - i.e. it shows all my asp.net markup but does not execute/render the page.

- I've run asp.net_regiis -i
- I've enabled asp.net 1.1 in the web services extensions.
- the virtual directory is setup to run under asp.net 1.1
- I've gone into the configuration option and made sure .aspx files are mapped to the aspnet_isapi.dll in the 1.1 framework folder.
- it is set up as an application and has an application name that matches the virtual directory

I know I must be missing SOMETHING but can't see what..

**edit**

another clue.. if I go into properties for the virtual directory, there is NO tab to select asp.net version.  I have to use the aspnetswitcher utility to select which framework to process a given vdir.

Comment: It is set as an application too? I.e has an application name etc.

Comment: You might try serverfault.com for server setup questions.  Although, this one is kind of borderline..

Answer (score 2):

If you use IIS 6.0 on your local workstation to connect to the servers IIS instance then the ASP.net tab doesn't display (go figure!).  If you remote onto the server then view it then it'll be there.

It would be unlikely that this would lead to the solution as if the incorrect .net version was selected you would still get either the page rendered or the yellow screen of death.

ASP.net 1.1 needed certain files in the root of the site to understand that it was a .net app.  Off the top of my head it was web.config, maybe global.  But 1.1 needed to be compiled (atleast in our instance) so you needed to copy up the bin folder with the related dll in also.

Good luck.